# Impala query with LIMIT 0

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, impala

Being production support team member, I investigate issues with various Impala queries and while researching on an issue , I see a team submits an Impala query with LIMIT 0  which obviously do not return any rows and then again without LIMIT 0 which gives them result. I guess they submit these queries from IBM Datastage. Before I question them why they do so.. wanted to check what could be a reason for someone to run with LIMIT 0. Is it just to check syntax or connection with Impala? I see a similar question discussed here in context of SQL but thought to ask anyway in Impala perspective.  Thanks Neel

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are partially correct.
Pls note, limit will process all the data and then apply limit clause.
`LIMIT 0` is mostly used to -

1. to check if syntax of SQL is correct. But impala do fetch all the records before applying limit. so SQL is completely validated. Some system may use this to check out the sql they generated automatically before actually applying it in server.
2. limit fetching lots of rows from a huge table or a data set every time you run a SQL.
3. sometime you want to create an empty table using structure of some other tables but do not want to copy store format, configurations etc.
4. dont want to burden the hue/any interface that is interacting with impala. All data will be processed but will not be returned.
5. performance test - this will somewhat give you an idea of run time of SQL. i used the word somewhat because its not actual time to complete but estimated time to complete a SQL.